# Не проходит подключение

Tags: c, многопоточность, сокет, linux

Вроде бы как все хорошо, родитель ждет 5 секунд, просыпается, включается потомок, но дескриптор `client_sockfd = 1`.

Есть подозрение, что что-то не так с завершением процессов.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
    int server_len, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_un server_address;
    struct sockaddr_un client_address;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("--ПАПА ПРОЦЕСС--");
       exit(0);
    }
    if (pid == 0)     // Потомок
    {
        server_sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(server_address.sun_path, "/home/coder/dataFaros");
        unlink(server_address.sun_path);
        server_len = sizeof(server_address);
        bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);
        printf("1serllver waiting\n");
        listen(server_sockfd, 5);
        sleep(5);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)  // Родитель
    {
        char ch = 'd';
        int g;
        client_len = sizeof(client_address);
        client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,
                           (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);
        printf("serllver waiting\n");
        g = read(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
        ch++;
        write(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
        printf("%d %d", g, client_sockfd);
        close(client_sockfd);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Fork error ");
        return -1;
    }
    wait(pid);
    return (0);

   /* на экран выводится:
      serllver waiting
      //проходит 5 секунд
      1serllver waiting
     -1 -1//это дискрипторы accept() и read()
   */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы бы лучше русским языком написали, что именно хотите сделать.

---

Сейчас у Вас вызовы `socket`, `bind` и `listen` в одном процессе, а `accept` в другом (естественно, там *одноименные* переменные совсем другие), а вот `connect`, нужный для установления связи `SOCK_STREAM` сокета вообще отсутствует.

---

В сети полно examples кода клиент-сервер. Полюбопытствуйте, как его пишут, а лучше для начала почитайте что-нибудь о многопроцессности и сокетах.

**Обновление**

Нашлось свободное время и я тоже написал примерчик.

*Unix Domain STREAM socket клиент и сервер в одном флаконе* (в смысле в одном файле). Сервер принимает строчки от клиента(ов) и выводит их в новом xterm окошкe.

Возможно найдете что-нибудь полезное в плане синхронизации процессов, запуска сервера в фоне, завершения  и т.д.

Расшаренный файл исходника:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzY1LBmZNGbwamZfVTc0YXhVb2M/view?usp=sharing

Если ссылка не читается, то сообщите в комментарии здесь и я переложу код на pastebin.

Если что-то непонятно - спрашивайте, постараюсь объяснить.

**Update**

Решил разместить обещанный код здесь

```
/*
  Совсем простой клиент-сервер.

  Сервер всегда запускается в дочернем процессе и обслуживает 1-го клиента.
  Клиент соединяется с этим сервером, шлет ему строки с клавиатуры
  и читает ответ.
  При завершении (Ctrl-D) клиента сервер тоже завершается.
  Все сообщения клиента и сервера выводятся в окно, в котором запущена программа

 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define ADDR "/tmp/usock_test1"
// макросы конкретно для этой программы
#define fatal(t) (kill(server, SIGTERM), perror(t), exit(-1))
#define sfatal(t) (kill(getppid(), SIGTERM), perror(t), exit(-1))

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int sock, addrlen, l, 
    synch[2];
  struct sockaddr_un saddr;
  char buf[LINE_MAX];
  pid_t server = 0;

  // результат этих 4 строк унаследуется в обеих процессах
  // он нужен для bind в сервере и connect в клиенте
  // клиент должен дождаться, пока сервер стартует.
  // синхронизируем их через pipe.
  saddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(saddr.sun_path, ADDR);
  addrlen = sizeof(saddr.sun_family) + strlen(ADDR);
  pipe(synch);

  if ((server = fork())) { // client
    puts("Client");
    // ждем старта сервера, если что-то пойдет не так, он убъет клиента
    read(synch[0], buf, 1);
    // сделаем сокет, уже отделившись от сервера
    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, addrlen))
      fatal("connect");

    // цикл чтения клавиатуры, отсылки серверу и чтения эха
    while (printf("Enter: "), fflush(stdout), fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
      buf[l = strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;  // удалим \n в конце строки
      if (write(sock, buf, l) != l)
        fatal("client write");
      if ((l = read(sock, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) < 1)
        fatal("client echo read");
      puts(buf);
    }

  } else { // server
    // у сервера и клиента сокеты должны быть разными (у каждого свой)
    sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    unlink(ADDR); // if other server die ...
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, addrlen) ||
        listen(sock, 5)) // что-то не так, убъем клиентский процесс
      sfatal("server");
    printf ("Server %d\n", (int)getpid());
    write(synch[1], "", 1); // все равно какой байт послать
    if (close(synch[1]) == -1)
      sfatal("server pipe");

    // инициализация сервера завершена
    int sfd = accept(sock, 0, 0);
    if (sfd == -1)
      sfatal("accept");
    // echo цикл обслуживания одного клиента
    while ((l = read(sfd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) > 0) {
      char buf2[LINE_MAX];
      buf[l] = 0;
      l = snprintf(buf2, LINE_MAX, "Echo: %s", buf);
      if (write(sfd, buf2, l) == -1)
        sfatal("server write");
    }
    perror("server exit");
    // с клиентом больше нет связи
    exit(0);    // для простоты ничего не поверяем и не чистим
  }

  return puts("\nBye") == EOF; // клиентская часть
}
```

Надеюсь, это действительно просто (хотя м.б. и не всегда хорошо), в коде довольно много комментариев.

Транслируете и запускаете без всяких ключей.

Comment: @kvars232, Обновил ответ.

Comment: @kvars232, обновил (см. **Update**) обещанным простейшим кодом.

Comment: @avp,ну да может быть=)
заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется использовать socket для двухстороннего общения (вместо двух pipe) между родительским и дочерним процессами, то можно использовать [`socketpair()`](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html#socketpair), вот [пример кода spair.c](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/examples/spair.c).

Comment: @Expert ,@avp, не знаю, как у вас, но у меня ваш код не работает connection refused.  
это + к  тому, что там не все либы включены.

Comment: @kvars232, не знаю, что у Вас за система. У меня никакие либы, кроме, естественно, libc, не нужны. Правда, команда `xterm` должна быть доступна (хотел, как покрасивей).

Т.е. компилите

    gcc unisock_servcli.c

и запускаете

    ./a.out -s

Потом из других окошек можно запускать просто

    ./a.out

и передавать строчки тому же серверу. Он их печатает в сввоем (xterm) окне.



(в начале кода есть комментарий, где все это написано).

Comment: @avp,извиняюсь,не либы,а хэдеры.
макрос WNOHANG например не работал.

Comment: Вообще-то, конечно, для `waitpid` надо было бы включить `#include <sys/wait.h>`, но у меня (Ubuntu, gcc 4.8.2 и в gcc  4.4.4 Red Hat) почему-то он подтягивается из `<stdlib.h>`.

У Вас `uname -a; gcc --version` что выводит?

Comment: @avp,извиняюсь за наглость конечно,просто это слишком сложный пример из за использования xterm.
не могли бы вы его упростить,что бы просто в сокет записывалась строка и считывалась на экран.
Я просто очень хочу разобраться с fork(),а то что нахожу в интернете,либо очень простые примеры,либо ваш=)

Comment: @avp,gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
да с этим я уже разобрался=)
только странно то,что программа не создает файл по указанному пути.
а так все работает..
но как я все равно понять не могу=)

Comment: @kvars232, хорошо. Как будет время изображу что-нибудь попроще с fork (т.е. клиент и сервер в одном файле).

А файл там, думаю, все же создается. Просто он же /tmp/.u-не-помню-дальше. Главное, что начинается с точки, значит просто `ls` его не отображает (надо `ls -a`).