# Передача и приём данных между процессами (C++ и Python)

Tags: c++, python, процесс

Есть программа, написанная на языке C++. Есть скрипт, написанный на языке Python (на самом деле не так важно, на каком языке). Необходимо оформить передачу данных между процессами этих программ. ОС с ядром GNU/Linux.

Видел разные варианты, но в основном всегда Python выступал в роли стартового приложения, которое запускало процесс программы на C++. Нужно наоборот, чтобы процесс C++ запускал скрипты Python.

Желательно, чтобы метод был универсальным, то есть чтобы можно было написать скрипт на другом языке и тем же методом обмениваться данными с ним.

Comment: named pipe попробуйте...

Comment: у вас вопрос "какие [методы IPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5) существуют"? Или "как запустить программу в c++, совместимым с выбранным IPC методом"? Какой метод выбрать зависит от вашей программы, какими данными и как конкретно вы хотите информацией обмениваться (где то простая pipe() работает, где то socket, где то  D-Bus используют, итд).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Получить Ввод/вывод процесса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/530413/23044)

Comment: @jfs у меня была проблема с последовательностью запуска процессов. Не мог найти инфу, где бы Python скрипт запускался после C++. Думаю, в моём случае named pipe вполне подходит. Спасибо!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо! Буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов реализации, действительно, несколько. Именно для моей задачи подошли именованные каналы (named pipes).

Пример реализации представлен ниже. Некоторые моменты обработки ошибок опущены, и сам код упрощён.

Фрагмент кода для C++

```
int pipeDescr, bytesNumber;
std::string outputPipeName{"inputPipe"}, inputPipeName{"outputPipe"};
char message[BUFSIZ];

if (mkfifo(inputPipeName.c_str(), 0777) || mkfifo(outputPipeName.c_str(), 0777))
{
    perror("mkfifo");
    return 1;
}

memset(message, '\0', BUFSIZ);
strcpy(message, "Sample message");

if ((pipeDescr = open(outputPipeName.c_str(), O_WRONLY)) <= 0)
{
    perror("open");
    return 2;
}

bytesNumber = write(pipeDescr, message, strlen(message) + 1);
if (bytesNumber <= 0)
{
    perror("write");
    return 3;
}
close(pipeDescr);

memset(message, '\0', BUFSIZ);
if ((pipeDescr = open(inputPipeName.c_str(), O_RDONLY)) <= 0)
{
    perror("open");
    return 2;
}

bytesNumber = read(pipeDescr, message, BUFSIZ);
if (bytesNumber <= 0)
{
    perror("read");
    return 4;
}
close(pipeDescr);

std::cout << "Got message: " << message << std::endl;

remove(inputPipeName.c_str());
remove(outputPipeName.c_str());
```

Фрагмент кода для Python

```
input_pipe_name = "inputPipe"
output_pipe_name = "outputPipe"

while not os.path.exists(input_pipe_name) and not os.path.exists(output_pipe_name):
    pass

try:
    pipe_descr = os.open(input_pipe_name, os.O_RDONLY)
    mes = os.read(pipe_descr, 1024)
    os.close(pipe_descr)
    print('Got: ' + str(mes))

    mes = 'Some answer'
    pipe_descr = os.open(output_pipe_name, os.O_WRONLY)
    os.write(pipe_descr, bytes(mes, 'UTF-8'))
    os.close(pipe_descr)
except OSEerror as exc:
    print('Exception: ' + str(exc))
```

Первой запускается процесс программы, написанной на C++, так как она создаёт файлы каналов.

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите в Linux из программы на C/C++ обмениваться со скриптом сообщениями, аналогично тому, как это можно делать сидя за терминалом (т.е. если скрипт читает stdin и пишет в stdout), то можете использовать вот такую фунцию

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pty.h>

FILE *
pty_execvp (char *argv[], pid_t *child)
{
  int pty;
  struct termios t;
  cfmakeraw(&t);

  if (!(*child = forkpty(&pty, 0, &t, 0))) {
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    fprintf(stderr, "exec %s: %m\n", argv[0]);
    exit(127);
  } else if (*child == -1)
    return 0;

  return fdopen(pty, "r+");
}
```

Аналогично [popen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) она возвращает `FILE *`, связанный с псевдотерминалом, на котором в новом процессе запускается скрипт (программа) с заданными аргументам.

Имя файла со скриптом и его аргументы передаются похоже тому, как в   функцию [execvp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) (только для имени запускаемого файла берется  первый аргумент скрипта).

По адресу в аргументе `child` помещается pid этого процесса.

Собирать надо с ключем -lutil (см. [man forkpty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty)).

Вот (несколько громоздкий и искусственный) пример ее использования

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <poll.h>


FILE *pty_execvp (char *argv[], pid_t *child);

int
fd_out (int fd, FILE *out, int tmout)
{
  struct pollfd fds = {fd, POLLIN};
  char buf[1024];
  int l, s = 0;

  while (poll(&fds, 1, tmout) > 0) {
    if ((l = read(fd, buf, 1024)) > 0) {
      s += l;
      fwrite(buf, 1, l, out);
    } else
      return -1;
  }

  return s;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *line = 0;
  size_t lsz;
  const char *cmd = "ls -l *.txt";
  FILE *in = popen(cmd, "r");
  if (!in)
    perror("popen"), exit(2);
  const char *pcmd[] = {
    "grep",
    "20",
    0
  };
  pid_t cpid;
  FILE *pty = pty_execvp((char **)pcmd, &cpid);
  if (pty)
    printf("run %s pid %ld\n", pcmd[0], (long)cpid);
  else
    exit(fputs("pty-exec error", stderr));

  while (getline(&line, &lsz, in) > 0) {
    fputs(line, pty);
    //    printf("> %s", line);
    if (fd_out(fileno(pty), stdout, 0) < 0) {
      perror("fd_out");
      break;
    }
  }

  while (fd_out(fileno(pty), stdout, 1) > 0);

  int rc;
  rc = pclose(in);
  printf("%s rc = %d\n",
     WIFEXITED(rc) ? "exit" : "terminated", WEXITSTATUS(rc));
  fclose(pty);
  pid_t fin = wait(&rc);
  if (WIFEXITED(rc)) 
    printf("Exit pid:%ld %d\n", (long)fin, WEXITSTATUS(rc));
  else if (WIFSIGNALED(rc))
    printf("Signal pid:%ld %d\n", (long)fin, WTERMSIG(rc));
  else
    printf("??? pid:%ld %d\n", (long)fin, rc);


  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Этот пример дает тот же результат, что и `ls -l *.txt | grep 20` и демонстрирует совместное использование popen с pty_exec для случая, когда мы заранее не знаем, какой будет ответ от `grep` на передаваемую строку.

Обратите внимание на таймаут в вызове `fd_out()` в конце программы.

Answer (score 0):

[Судя по вашему вопросу о сигналах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573078/23044), я бы упростил взаимодействие процессов, например, вы можете писать и читать, используя стандартный ввод/вывод в Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(work_func(line), flush=True)
```

[Чтобы перенаправить ввод/вывод дочернего процесса в С после `fork()` можно `dup2()` использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/530413/23044). Или даже ещё проще, используя [`socketpair`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/379225/23044). Если это требуется, вы можете общую память использовать ([`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html), [`posix_ipc`](https://bitbucket.org/philip_semanchuk/posix_ipc/src/18810fbace09a14d3da5dfe345657e927d63078d/demo/)).

Comment: Скорее всего мне будут нужны стандартные потоки ввода/вывода в их типичном смысле. Но в любом случае спасибо, буду иметь ввиду!

Comment: @AccumPlus: [`sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` это стандартные потоки ввода/вывода в их типичном смысле.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572737/23044)

Comment: я имел ввиду, что мне пригодится вывод на экран. Хотя для этого можно взять stderr... В общем есть пища для размышлений.